# Why change idea.vmoptions not works?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

I change the default properties `-Xmx750m` to `-Xmx10m` in idea.vmoptions,and then I restart the idea.

But I use `jstat <pid>` it show below:

```
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
48640.0 48640.0  0.0    0.0   28160.0  23283.0   237056.0   191368.3  150632.0 141327.4 19072.0 16098.7     78    0.683  11      2.252    2.935
```

The `OU` cost `186m` in memery,it show the change in idea.vmoptions dons't work.

Then I use `jinfo <PID>` it show below:

```
VM Flags:
...
-XX:InitialHeapSize=10485760 -XX:MaxHeapSize=2147483648
...

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: 
-Xms10m 
-Xmx10m 
-XX:InitialHeapSize=10485760 
-XX:MaxHeapSize=10485760
```

It shows the `MaxHeapSize` is not work!

Here is my jdk version.

```
❯ java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

There is my idea.log:

```
2022-07-06 21:20:06,629 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2022-07-06 21:20:06,641 [     12]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/zsh -l -i -c '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/printenv' '/var/folders/1g/5t2m1f0d2sn7q77lyxyfgtw00000gn/T/intellij-shell-env.7181435418652734462.tmp' 
2022-07-06 21:20:06,666 [     37]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-213.7172.25, 16 Mar 2022 00:34) 
2022-07-06 21:20:06,666 [     37]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (12.2.1, x86_64) 
2022-07-06 21:20:06,668 [     39]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - id redefinition ([row,col,system-id]: [2,3,"product classpath"]) 
2022-07-06 21:20:06,672 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.14.1+1-b1751.46 (JetBrains s.r.o.) 
2022-07-06 21:20:06,673 [     44]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.14.1+1-b1751.46 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2022-07-06 21:20:06,673 [     44]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM options: [-Xms10m, -Xmx10m, -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m, -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50, -XX:CICompilerCount=2, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -ea, -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false, -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="", -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true, -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true, -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off, -XX:ErrorFile=/Users/zhangmingyuan/java_error_in_idea_%p.log, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/zhangmingyuan/java_error_in_idea.hprof, -Xmx2048m, -javaagent:/Users/zhangmingyuan/.jetbrains/jetbrains-agent-v3.2.0.0f1f.69e=6e68f9eb,f9fF1I/ygZI7Ff14sigGMZmZ7KJkhsM364o6exiukAqGORVXN1e4Fk4B8+hGSl5B+iLp9nIA2pSNhNGlxnDgSV3xC85CGVvWY9SWa+ECeWhJZ1+hitDPCNw5lKaRBnxIKhAfQ3aJl4S5WmrOkfKoIuz3UXVoX7hZGxofqQtzfuc, -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Users/zhangmingyuan/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/idea.vmoptions, -Dsplash=true, -Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents, -Didea.jre.check=true, -Didea.executable=idea, -Djava.system.class.loader=com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader, -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2021.3, -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains]
```

There is my environment:

- OS:MacOS:12.2.1
- IDEA:2021.3.0

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple JVMs installed, and IntelliJ is using a different version - can you check that, and add that detail? `java -version`

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?